# datatable column dropdown sorting

Tags: php, datatable

I am using datatable in php. I am able to sort the value inside the data table. But not able to sort the value in drop down. It is not displayed in random manner[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyzsU.png)

Answer (score 0):

That dropdown is your Datatable filter. You can sort values for a particular column but you can not sort values shown in your form element. Try sorting these values before you are looping in your dropdown.
For this type of filter, I prefer using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)